# Fastlane Gym: Possible to only archive without export?

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-gym

I'm using the following fastfile:

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Build a new xcarchive for the app store"
  lane :release do
  build_app(workspace: "App.xcworkspace", 
            scheme: "App-iOS", 
            skip_codesigning: true)
end
```

I'd like to only build the archive without exporting. Is this possible with fastlane gym? What parameter should I use?

Currently the archive succeeds, but since it's missing export/codesigning info, it fails to export it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Per https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gym/, you'll want a combination of `skip_codesigning: true` and `skip_package_ipa: true`

```
      skip_codesigning: true,
      skip_package_ipa: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an xcarchive action for this task.

Looks like `skip_package_ipa: true` also does the trick.